# defining methods on jQuery objects doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have the following:

```
$.fn.myFunction = (action) ->
  console.log "hello!"
```

and when i call

```
$(".myDiv").myFunction()
```

it works fine in firefox, chrome, and safari but it fails in IE.

Comment: Is that literally the syntax you're using?

Comment: It's coffeescript right?

Comment: Older Internet Explorer does not have `console.log`.

Comment: `$.fn.myFunction = function() { console.log("hello!"); };` should work just fine

Comment: Are you opening the console so that console.log will work? (`F12`)

Comment: no i'm using the newest version of ie. That was a typo of, that meant to be selecting the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is one that looks for an element with tag "myDiv":

```
<myDiv> There is no such element in standard HTML </myDiv>
```

Internet explorer tends not to like that. Are you really "inventing" elements?

Perhaps you meant to look for this:

```
<div id='myDiv'> This is more like it. </div>
```

In that case, your selector would be "#myDiv":

```
$('#myDiv').myFunction();
```

Note that `console` doesn't exist before (I think) IE8.

Comment: thanks, that was a typo. I meant to have a period before to be selecting a class.

Comment: OK well see if it works when you have the IE debugging tools open for the page. If they're not open, then "console" won't work.